# why R studio works fine with dataframe but doesn't work using excel file using "shiny"&"highcharter"?

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, r-highcharter

i m trying to create an interactive plot using highcharter and to be dependent on the selectinput.
The below code is working perfect with the data frame, but once uploading the excel file the R studio can't execute the 'amount function' , you can try with this spreadsheet which contains exactly the same data

here is the error message:
"Warning: Error in : object 'amount' not found"

```
library (shinyjs)
library (tidyr)
library (data.table)
library (highcharter)
library (dplyr)
library (shinydashboard)
library (shiny)

header <- dashboardHeader()
body <- dashboardBody(
selectInput("selectid","Select a Measurement",choices=c("a","b","c"),selected = "a"),
highchartOutput("Working"))
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$Working <- renderHighchart({
# Make the initial data.
summarized <- dat %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarize(Quantity = sum(!!sym(input$selectid)))
summarized <- arrange(summarized, desc(Quantity))
tibbled <- tibble(name = summarized$x, y = summarized$Quantity)
# This time, click handler is needed.
drilldownHandler <- JS("function(event)
{Shiny.onInputChange('ClickedInput', event.point.drilldown);}")
# Also a message receiver for later async drilldown data has to be set.
# Note in the JS: message.point is going to be the point ID. Highcharts addSeriesAsDrilldown need a point to attach
#   the drilldown series to. This is retrieved via chart.get which takes the ID of any Highcharts Element.
#   This means: IDs are kind of important here, so keep track of what you assign.
installDrilldownReceiver <- JS("function() {
                               var chart = this;
                               Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('drilldown', function(message) {
                               var point = chart.get(message.point)
                               chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(point, message.series);
                               });
 }")
highchart() %>%
  # Both events are on the chart layer, not by series. 
  hc_chart(events = list(load = installDrilldownReceiver, drilldown = drilldownHandler)) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  # Note: We add a drilldown directive (= name) to tell Highcharts that this has a drilldown functionality.
  hc_add_series(tibbled, "column", hcaes(x = name, y = y, drilldown = name, id = name), color = "#E4551F") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%
  hc_drilldown(allowPointDrilldown = TRUE)
})
# Drilldown handler to calculate the correct drilldown
observeEvent(input$ClickedInput, {
# We will code the drill levels to be i.e. Farm_Car. By that we calculate the next Sub-Chart.
levels <- strsplit(input$ClickedInput, "_", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
# This is just for generalizing this function to work in all the levels and even be expandable to further more levels.
resemblences <- c("x", "y", "z")
dataSubSet <- dat
# We subsequently narrow down the original dataset by walking through the drilled levels
for (i in 1:length(levels)) {
  dataSubSet <- dat[dat[[resemblences[i]]] == levels[i],]
}    
# Create a common data.frame for all level names.
normalized <- data.frame(category = dataSubSet[[resemblences[length(levels) + 1]]], amount = dataSubSet[, input$selectid])
summarized <- normalized %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarize(Quantity = sum(amount))
summarized <- arrange(summarized, desc(Quantity))
tibbled <- tibble(name = summarized$category, y = summarized$Quantity)
# Preparing the names and drilldown directives for the next level below.
# If already in "Farm_Car", the name for column "Bob" will be "Farm_Car_Bob"
nextLevelCodes = lapply(tibbled$name, function(fac) {
  paste(c(levels, as.character(fac)), collapse = "_")
}) %>% unlist
tibbled$id = nextLevelCodes
# This is dynamic handling for when there is no further drilldown possible.
# If no "drilldown" property is set in the data object, Highcharts will not let further drilldowns be triggered.
if (length(levels) < length(resemblences) - 1) {
  tibbled$drilldown = nextLevelCodes
}    
# Sending data to the installed Drilldown Data listener.
session$sendCustomMessage("drilldown", list(
  series = list(
    type = "column",name = paste(levels, sep = "_"),
          data = list_parse(tibbled)
    ),
  # Here, point is, as mentioned above, the ID of the point that triggered the drilldown.
  point = input$ClickedInput
  ))
  })
output$trial <- renderText({input$ClickedInput})
}

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Sorry, but there is no spreadsheet that you mention above and `dat` is not defined in your code?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362)